# Invalid union member

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, visual-studio-2013, unions

Is there a way in Visual Studio to handle non-trivial unions. The following code is running fine using `g++ -std=c++11` but VS complains:

> invalid union member -- class "Foo" has a disallowed member function

The code is as follows:

```
struct Foo {
    int value;
    Foo(int inV = 0) : value(inV) {}
};

union CustomUnion {
    CustomUnion(Foo inF) : foo(inF) {}
    CustomUnion(int inB) : bar(inB) {}
    int bar;
    Foo foo;
};

int main() {
    CustomUnion u(3);
    return 0;
}
```

Is there a way in Visual Studio to support this kind of unions (compilation option for instance)? Or should I change my code, and if so by what?

Comment: The only information on this topic I found with a quick research was in [Bjarne Stroustrup's C++ FAQ, unions (generalized)](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#unions). Hope this helps you further.

Answer (score 8):

I agree with @Shafik Yaghmour but there is an easy workaround.
Just put your `foo` member into an `unnamed struct` like so:

```
union CustomUnion {
    struct{
        Foo foo;
    };
    int bar;
};
```

Answer (score 4):

[Visual Studio does not support unrestricted unions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx) which is a *C++11* feature that allows unions to contain *non-POD* types, in your case *Foo* has a non-trivial constructor since you have defined one.

I don't see any reference that says when Visual Studio will support this so it does not seem like you will get this to work as is in Visual Studio. Although there seems to be [many who do want this feature supported](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2985431-please-add-unrestricted-union-support-www-open-st).

The only way I can see to get to work would be to remove your user defined constructor from *Foo*. That would mean manually initializing `foo` in the *CustomUinon* constructor.

A good reference article would be: [C++11 Standard Explained: 1. Unrestricted Union](http://cpp11standard.blogspot.com/2012/11/c11-standard-explained-1-unrestricted.html) .

Comment: Hm unfortunately it seems to confirm that there is no way in Visual Studio to handle it... Thanks for the confirmation though.

Answer (score 1):

As described in msdn, union just accesses members:
 1) class type without any constructors or destructors, 
 2) static member,
 3) class type without user defined assignment operation(override =).

Answer (score 0):

I've received this same error, but my situation may be different. Turns out that the union is looking for a default constructor.

So within my class I had to do this:

```
struct Foo
{
    union
    {
        Bar bar; // intellisense will still show error, but you can ignore it.
    };
};
```

And within you **Bar class**, instead of creating a traditional default constructor `Bar();` and defining it, change it to `Bar() = default;` and erase your default constructor definition in your .cpp file. You will still see the error for Bar bar, because intellisense doesn't know exactly what's going on. Your application will still compile regardless if this helps.