# Invalid union member in VS2013 but not 2015

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2013

I have a class

```
class myTestClass
{
public:
    int a;
    myTestClass();
    ~myTestClass();
private:
    float b;
};
```

Which I am trying to add to a union

```
union myUnion
{
    myTestClass mt;
    int l;
    float f;
};
```

In Visual Studio 2013 I get the error `Invalid union member -- class "myTestClass" has a disallowed member function. This message appears to be caused by the constructor (not other function which I've tried adding).

Testing in Visual Studio 2015, the error seems to go away. Unfortunately the project is in VS2013 and can't be moved (or at least it won't be for this one little problem).

Having a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21968635/invalid-union-member) it appears that the construct is considered a disallowed member function, but is allowed in C++11. I guess this part of the spec was introduced between VS13 and VS15.

Why is the constructor disallowed specifically and not other function? Is there any way around this in VS2013? One of the answers in the question mentioned above suggested putting the class in a struct in the union. However my union is already in another struct and I am trying to avoid unnecessary layers to the code.